# How Do I Access the Active Cell in a Non-active Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

As I flip through the tabs of an Excel (Office 365 MSO 16.0.12527.20880 64-bit) workbook, I can see that Excel remembers the most recently selected cell in each sheet.

Can I access this in VBA? I know I can use

```
myString = ActiveCell.Text
```

to get the active cell on the active sheet. But, I'm thinking that, since Excel knows what cell is selected on the other sheet, I should be able to get it without activating it.  Wouldn't this be nice?

```
myString = Sheets("OtherSheet").SelectedCell.Text
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no active cell on an inactive sheet.  You will need to capture that using an event.

Comment: But it knows... :-/

Comment: Turn off screen updating, activate the sheet, get the selection, then switch back ?

Comment: Could be wrong, but I thought I saw something a while back about parsing the underlying xml in an Excel file to do this.

Comment: This was 2013. https://www.msofficeforums.com/excel-programming/17459-finding-selection-inactive-worksheet.html. They couldn't do it then and I don't think it can be done now.

Comment: @BigBen You're right.  I had a quick look into a workbooks xml.  There is an element in each of the SheetName.xml files (in the xl folder) called `activeCell` that record the reference.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I couldn't remember if it was you or maybe Ron Rosenfeld who had done this previously. I thought it was Ron. I don't know where it was demonstrated though.

Comment: @StoneGiant _But it knows_ yes, but the excel vba object model does not expose _everything_ it knows.

Comment: Well Bummer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

No. It wouldn't be nice because of the provisions I would have to make for there not having been any selection yet and/or the selection not being the one I let me code think it was. All of this changes when there is a controlled environment where I, say, select a cell on one sheet, switch sheets, and then want the contents of the just selected cell. In this kind of environment it's a lot easier to control the process.

- Declare a public variable (perhaps a variant, string or a range)
- In the *Worksheet_Deactivate* procedure, assign either the cell or its value to the variable.
- Use the variable wherever you need it.